# Access IIS7 with local ip in server 2008 r2?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, vmware

Strange thing, I have no problem with other two server 2008 r2 and Win7.

I can access to the IIS7 using localhost or 127.0.0.1, but if I try to access this server with it network IP, the IPv4 Address in ipconfig.  It doesn't connect to the the IIS7 and gave connection timeout... I tried to turn off the windows firewall, and it still the same...

I wonder what will be the possible problem? The IIS7 was setup with using WebPlatform and is locate inside VMware with using NAT as network setting.

Thanks in advance...

===========
Edit: Route Print and netstat result

```
===========================================================================
Active Routes:

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.107.2  192.168.107.129     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    192.168.107.0    255.255.255.0         On-link   192.168.107.129    266
  192.168.107.129  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.107.129    266
  192.168.107.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.107.129    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.107.129    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.107.129    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 11    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    266 fe80::db0:f38:6194:3b17/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

netstat /an | find /i ":80 "

> TCP    0.0.0.0:80
>   0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING   TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0
>   LISTENING

Comment: Use *route print* in a windows command prompt window to see if there is a route to the local IP address. The other thing to check is whether IIS is listening on localhost only. To do this, check *netstat /an | find /i ":80 "*. If it's listening on all IP addresses, you should see something like **TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING**

Comment: hmm so I think is missing an interface 192.168.107.129 to 127.0.0.1?  So I tried route add 127.0.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.107.129 METRIC 1, and I can see it added into the route print, but it still doesn't work.....

Comment: Hmm, indeed. It looks like everything should be hanging together.  Another thought: does your browser have a proxy enabled?  If so, turn it off or add your local IP address to the non-proxied addresses.

Comment: oh right! I totally forgot about the proxy, it working now, thanks a lot! ah...wasted so much time on this little thing....  Thanks a lot...

Comment: Great!  Mind up-voting my comment? :-)

Comment: I wish I can vote your commment, but my network inn office doesn't allow me to login into any of my email account, so I couldn't login into StackOverlow too (has to post without account...)

Comment: No worries! Glad to have helped!